# How to get full dynamic URL with expressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a middleware to check acl, but I cannot find a way to get the URL of dynamic routes. Example : '/user/:id/movie/:name'. I'm able to get the url but it's already filled with the id and name, how can I get the raw URL for this dynamic routes ? (I already checked baseUrl, originalUrl, url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So express doesn't know what is the end dynamic URL due to `router`. Each route can be appended to any URL prefix.

in your case:

- `user/:id` - is the prefix
- `movie/:name` - is the route

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// add empty urlTemplate on each incoming request
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.urlTemplate = "";
    next();
});

// create route
var router = express.Router()
const urlTemplateMove = '/movie/:name';
const moveRoute = router.get(urlTemplateMove, function (req, res) {
    req.urlTemplate += urlTemplateMove; // <- append current route urlTemplate 

    console.log(req.urlTemplate);
    res.json(req.urlTemplate);
});

// append urlTemplate on each route
const urlTemplateUser = '/user/:id';
app.use(urlTemplateUser, (req, res, next) => {
    req.urlTemplate += urlTemplateUser;
    moveRoute(req, res, next);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Note if you're not interested in using `router` you just create the URL as in a higher scope and then you will have access to it in the callback.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const urlTemplate = '/user/:id/movie/:name';
app.get(urlTemplate, function (req, res) {
    console.log(urlTemplate);
    res.json(urlTemplate);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: Really interesting way of doing this, thanks for the answer. I came up with some other tricky way (checking req.route.path and mixing this up with the req.baseUrl but if I got another layer of router i'll lose track of some information) but your solution seems more consistent than mine.