# Node.js - Using input parsed from form to route to a specific URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to allow a user to enter their name and have it added to the URL.

for example if the users input is John it redirects the user to "/profile/John"

So far I have tried to define a variable name from the parsed input from my html form.

html code;

```
<h4>Search for your profile by entering your name below.</h4>
<form class="" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Node code;

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var name = String(req.body.name);
});
app.post("/profile/:" + name, (req,res)=>{
  var data = {
    age: 19,
    job: 'Student',
    hobbies: ['Fishing','Video games','Anime','Basketball']
  };

  res.render('profile',{name: req.params.name, data: data});
});
```

But I get this error;

```
                     ^
app.get('/profile/:' + name, (req,res)=>{
                       ^


ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   // var name = String(req.body.name);
});
```

Above is not necessary part.
You should handle like below

```
app.post("/profile/:name", (req,res)=>{
var name = String(req.params.name)
  var data = {
    age: 19,
    job: 'Student',
    hobbies: ['Fishing','Video games','Anime','Basketball']
  };

  res.render('profile',{name: req.params.name, data: data});
});
```

You can check the details in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998651/how-to-get-full-dynamic-url-with-expressjs)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put name inside the path quotes,
like this

`app.get('/profile/:name',(req,res) =>{ }`

the : after / indicates that the next value is dynamic

check out   [ExpressJS - URL Building](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_url_building.htm)

Comment: No error message now but the request is stuck on pending when i enter an input and search